# Solaris 10 восстановление из flar образа

Tags: unix, solaris

Хочу мигрировать сервер Sunfire v240 c архитектурой sun4u и ОС Solaris 10 update 6 на LDOM сервер (виртуальный) с архитектурой sun4v. Согласно инструкции http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/821-0436/samekernel/index.html добавляю в файл /var/sadm/system/admin/.platform строку
PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4v.

```
# cat /var/sadm/system/admin/.platform
PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
INST_ARCH=sparc
PLATFORM_NAME=SUNW,SPARCstation-fusion
PLATFORM_ID=SUNW,SPARCstation-fusion
IN_PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
PLATFORM_NAME=FJSV,GP
PLATFORM_ID=FJSV,GP
IN_PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
PLATFORM_NAME=FJSV,GPUU
PLATFORM_ID=FJSV,GPUU
IN_PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
PLATFORM_NAME=SUNW,Ultra-Enterprise-10000
PLATFORM_ID=SUNW,Ultra-Enterprise-10000
IN_PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
PLATFORM_NAME=SUNW,Ultra-1
PLATFORM_ID=SUNW,Ultra-1
IN_PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4u
PLATFORM_GROUP=sun4v
```

Запускаю создание образа на подмонтированный NFS каталог

flarcreate -n S10U6hybrid -U "content_architectures=sun4u,sun4v"\ -c -x /oracle /mnt/S10U6hybrid.flar

```
# ls -lh /mnt/S10U5hybrid.flar
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 36G Jun 20 15:44 /mnt/S10U5hybrid.flar

# flar -i /mnt/S10U5hybrid.flar
archive_id=dc099d1c8d058f90b6c1bc9f0157a86e
files_archived_method=cpio
creation_date=20160620081531
creation_master=tjk-moz
content_name=S10U6hybrid
creation_node=hostname
creation_hardware_class=sun4u
creation_platform=SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
creation_processor=sparc
creation_release=5.10
creation_os_name=SunOS
creation_os_version=Generic_150400-24
files_compressed_method=none
files_archived_size=38710129967
files_unarchived_size=38710129967
content_architectures=sun4v
type=FULL
content_architectures=sun4u,sun4v
/usr/sbin/flar[40]: print: bad option(s)
```

наличие этой строки /usr/sbin/flar[40]: print: bad option(s) настораживает, но у меня получались образы и без нее, так как я неоднократно пробовал пересоздавать образа и даже создавал образ другого сервера с тем же конечным результатом, о котором ниже

На виртуальном сервере гружусь с Jumpstart версии Solaris 10 update 7 (на один update выше оригинального сервера, увы, оригинальный не возможно скачать где-то)

```
ok> boot net - w
```

Пробовал грузиться и с опцией - install, результат тот же

Выбираю опцию Flash install, ввожу адрес путь до NFS и получаю ERROR: Could not find archive
перехожу в single user режим, копирую образ на локальный диск, указываю путь до него и снова ERROR: Could not find archive
Выкладка с Jumpstart single user

```
# df -h
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/ramdisk-root:a        170M   165M     0K   100%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                    30G   352K    30G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
swap                    30G    99M    30G     1%    /tmp
/tmp/dev                30G    99M    30G     1%    /dev
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
192.168.0.30:/sol10u7_install
                       300G   239G    58G    81%    /cdrom
df: cannot statvfs /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1: Operation not applicable
df: cannot statvfs /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1: Operation not applicable
swap                    30G     8K    30G     1%    /tmp/root/var/run
/usr/sbin/install.d/install_config
                       170M   165M     0K   100%    /tmp/_install_config
192.168.0.29:/opt/moz/
                       404G    61G   339G    16%    /mnt

# ls -l /mnt
total 126132592
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody   nobody   38586476847 Jun 20 15:44 S10U5hybrid.flar
```

Пробовал загрузку c jumpstart Solaris 10u11, пробовал находить образ по FTP, каждый раз ошибка нахождения файла. Как ее решить?

Answer (score 1):

Корень проблемы в том, что на исходной системе отсутствуют платформозависимые sun4v файлы, которые необходимы для работы. Собственно они есть только на исходном iso с дистрибутивом и во flash архив попасть не могут потому что их просто нет на исходной системе.

В инструкции, на которую Вы указываете об этом тоже написано:

**At this point, the Sun4V machine may not boot.**

Для решения проблемы документ предлагает

**Upgrade the Sun4V machine using either a network image or a DVD image.**

Во время этого **апгрейда** (нужно использовать Jumpstart в режиме install_type    upgrade, либо как советует указанная Вами инструкция **boot the Sun4V image from that network image, selecting the upgrade option**) на систему должны автоматически установиться недостающие платформозависимые sun4v файлы. Таким образом задумманная Вами затея получается довольно трудозатратной.

Самый простой способ быстро перетащить много старых sun4u систем на sun4v - не плодить домены, а перетащить их в Branded-зоны. Для этого сначало необходимо создать конфигурацию для зоны

```
zonecfg -z zonename
   create -t SUNWsolaris10
   set zonepath=/zones/zonename
   set ip-type=exclusive
   add net
     set physical=s10zone0
   end
   verify
   commit
   exit
```

, затем загрузить ее содержимое из архива.

```
zoneadm -z zonename install -a /path/to/achhive.flar -u
```